# Interactive Shell in Web App

Tags: shell

I'm making an React/Meteor application that sort of emulates sites like code academy with an javascript editor present (using `react-codemirror`). I'm wanting to add an interactive shell to this as well. Anyone know of resources to do this? I found `terminal.js` on the npm page but was curious if anyone knew of other modules or resources.